# Chrome Rending Extra Whitespace at the End of Web Page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I seem to be getting some extra white-space at the bottom of my page in chrome (IE, FF and safari all work)

I can replicate the issue in Firefox by setting both the `<body>` and `<html>` elements to `height: 100%;`

I can get rid of the issue by setting `overflow: hidden;` but this won't work because if the document grows past the height of the window i won't get scroll bars.

The `<html>` element does have a background color.

demo: http://futurewebblog.com/demos/movie-searcher/

**Update: False alarm, it seems to be an isolated issue with my version of chrome, i just did a quick update and it fixed it straight away**

Comment: If overflow:hidden; doesn't work, have you tried overflow:auto; ? Can you supply a live link for us to take a look at?

Comment: It's not happening in my Chrome (Chrome 12 on OS X).

Comment: @alex hmm, i'm using chrome 11 on PC, might be a specific chrome issue with this version

Comment: nothing here either (Chrome 11 Win7)

Comment: I'm not seeing this either. Chrome 12 on Vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's said to be a webkit bug that you can solve by

```
html {background-color: #000;}
```

with the color of your choice.

Comment: OP says "The <html> element does have a background color" ...so i'm not seeing how this helps

Comment: @Thomas Shields. Yes, but I believe it was added afterwards.

Comment: thought so too but the revision history says otherwise. that quote was in the original post.